# #if preprocessor directive in Clips Rules

Tags: clips

can any one suggest how to use the preprocessor directive like #if #elif And #endif in CLips rules

#if Vehicle_model

(eq ?Vehicle-type "test")

#endif

)

Answer (score 0):

CLIPS doesn't support a preprocessor so you would either have to modify the code to add one or use a general purpose preprocessor such as GPP (https://logological.org/gpp).